# Do you need to use an objectify iterator before getting the cursor?

Tags: objectify

Say I have a limited query like this:

`Query<Buns> query = ofy().load().type(Buns.class).limit(100);`

If I execute the limited query with `query.list()`, then get the cursor with `query.iterator().getCursor()`, will the cursor point to the next chunk of 100 results, or the first chunk of results?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you request an `iterator()` from the query, you get a new result set. Each iterator is independent.

A `Query<?>` is really a query definition.